# how to delete single fcm notification which comes when app is background?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I  am developing an app where I am getting FCM notification, in that when the app is open `onMessageRecieved()` method triggers and I am notifying message based on tag and id and deleting notification based on id and tag. But when the app is in background `onMesasageRecived()` is not calling. How to attach id and tag notification or how to delete single notification based on some id when I am getting notification from the background.

> see onMessageReceived

```
 @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
............
     notificationManager.notify("tag", notificationId, notification);
.......
}
```

> for deleting the message

```
  private void clearNotifications() {

        NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        nMgr.cancel("tag",notificationId);
    }
```

> this is working
>   but when the app is closed code is not working.
>   can we notify or attach tag and id from the serverside payload

Comment: exactly where are you cancelling ? where did you call `clearNotifications();`

Comment: on opening  the custom activity

Comment: you said that the app is in background !! activity is not upfront then !!

Comment: I have two notification id 0 and 1,. on custom activity I want to delete only notification witch id equal 1

Comment: after you open the customer activity ryt ?

Comment: Santanu app is in backgroung but when i willl open  app i want to delete only notification whos id ==0

Comment: after you open the activity after clicking notification you want to cancel it in onCreate of that particular activity ryt ?

Comment: _when the app is in background onMesasageRecived() is not calling_    -->It won't be invoked if app is in **background** and the message sent is **Notification Message** . And in the case of data message,  You don't need to flag and id at all. Just use `content intent` for notification (your desired activity)and also `AUTO_CANCEL` flag.

Comment: ye Santanu I want to delete in on create  but only notification who having  id equal ==1

Answer (score 2):

If you check out the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options?hl=pt-br) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) you'll see that if you have a `notification` payload your notification will be delivered to the system tray directly when your app is in the background, there's no way to intercept that. The same will happen if you have a notification payload with an option data payload, the notification will go straight to the tray and the data payload will be delivered to the intent of the launcher activity.

```
{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification":{
      "title":"Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "body":"great match!"
    }
  }
}
```

As you're checking the id/tag in the `onMessageReceive` method, what you can do to guarantee that it will always call the `onMessageReceived` method is to remove the notification payload from your notification and add just a data payload. All `data` payloads are delivered to the `onMessageReceived` method.

```
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "data":{
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "body" : "great match!",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To have `onMessageReceived()` method called when app in background, you have to remove "notification" key and its payload from your messages and  only include "data" key and its payload.

Before: (message with both notification and data payloads)

```
{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification":{
      "title":"Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "body":"great match!"
    },
    "data" : {
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
  }
}
```

After: (data message only)

```
{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "data" : {
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
  }
}
```

Because only data message which including "data" key can get `onMessageReceive()` method called when your app in background as described in [this document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging#receive_and_handle_topic_messages).

One more thing: if you target your app for devices with Android 8.0 and higher, you have to register your app's notification channel as specified in [this document](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#Priority), otherwise message notifications will not appear.